# Live streaming JPEG images in tvOS Swift

Tags: swift, streaming, swift5, tvos, mjpeg

We are using ZoneMinder live cam streaming software where it streams JPEG images (MJPEG), this works well if applies to HTML `<img/>` tag which shows auto-updated images every 30 seconds:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="https://oursite/cgi-bin-zm/nph-zms?scale=50&width=1920px&height=1080px&mode=jpeg&maxfps=30&monitor=21&connkey=150000&rand=1598607232" width="860px" height="340px"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using Swift 5 I tried to print the URL/image to an `UIImageView` in the following way:

```
let liveURL = URL(string:"https://oursite/cgi-bin-zm/nph-zms?scale=50&width=1920px&height=1080px&mode=jpeg&maxfps=30&monitor=21&connkey=150000&rand=1598607232")
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)
        
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, request, error) in
     guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
     print("Download Finished")
     DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
         self?.imgLive.image = UIImage(data: data)
     }
}.resume()
```

Initially, I was having self-signed SSL error accessing the domain, this resolved after using self as `URLSessionDelegate`.

I confirm with the above code-block I can able to fetch any regular image from the other remote location.

Using our live-feed image provider URL, however I see the `data` under `dataTask` method always is 0 bytes.

How I can access such URL provides streaming images, and displaying effectively in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I don't need to re-invent the wheel when someone already invented it.

https://github.com/WrathChaos/MJPEGStreamLib - This worked well for me to stream MJPEG images from a remote location!